# MySQL connector c++ does not contain libmysql.lib

Tags: c++, mysql, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So since Saturday I am trying to setup MySQL Connector C++ with VS2012. I'll leave it without commentary that I had to download 1xx mb Boost libs just to run simple query from my program lol. Nevertheless it doesn't work.

The problem is that even when I setup everything correctly (following MySQL Connector Manual from official site) it just can't work - because the latest package that I downloaded does not contains files listed in manual. Manual states:

Add the lib/opt directory into the Additional Library Directories text field. This enables the library file libmysql.lib to be found.

But there is no libmysql.lib and/or libmysql.dll.

When building I receive obvious error: error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libmysql.lib'

How can I setup this to work correctly?

P.S. I copy the question from stackoverflow, because i have exactly the same question, but noone answer this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Download mysql server from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/. It contains libmysql.lib. After you link your project with libmysql.lib you will get error "Missing libmysql.dll" or something like that, and then you'll have to copy libmysql.dll to release folder

And I'm not sure how this will work with you but I had to download 32bit version of server.

P.S. I know about 2 weeks passed from your question but it's never too late, it might help someone.

Comment: Note that libmysql.lib is only for Windows.

Comment: I had a `libmysql.lib` file in my MySQL Workbench. I used it and it worked.